# What's done in this line of code?

Tags: c++

I am new to C++. Could someone please tell me what is done in this line of code?

```
const Doub RADIX = numeric_limits<Doub>::radix;
```

Comment: I guess it's some kind of `double`?!

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you want to know?

Comment: I fail to see how this is a useful question for our repository of knowledge. Seems more like a personal helpdesk question. Did you try asking a friend to walk you through your code?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Agreed. For the same reason your toddler's scribbling isn't likely to make it to the Smithsonian, this question doesn't seem like a great candidate for upvoting on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DavidFrye: To be fair, my toddler's scribbling is _awesome_ and should definitely be displayed in the National Gallery :D (I don't care much for your Smithsonian, though!)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Well, _your_ toddler is an exception, I'm sure of it! Anyway, I'm not actually much of an art gallery buff, the Smithsonian is just the first thing that came to mind. Either way, I totally agree with you - SO should not be a helpdesk full of one-off questions that'll never be useful to a wider audience in the future. Sorry OP, this question is just _bad_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It creates a constant value named `RADIX`, which is the radix value for the non-standard type `Doub`. A radix for a floating-point type is the base of the exponent of its representation (usually 2, but since we don't know what Doub is, it could also be a custom numeric class which uses a different base for the exponent of its floating-point representation).

Comment: Please check this for more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/daf4e9y7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
template <class T> numeric_limits;
```

Provides information about the properties of arithmetic types. And i'm thinking "doub" is a typedef.
So the arithmetic type of "radix" is being described

```
#include <limits>
```

should be used
please visit http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/
for more information about the use of numeric_limits